# Filter button won't reload and filter information

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

Hello I'm trying to filter by graduation status in my Index pages with a dropdown filter but when clicking the Process button the pages wont filter...

What am I doing wrong here?

[Index Page showing filter button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQov5.png)

View :

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = 
     "FilterForm" }))
                        {
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>


        @Html.DropDownList("GraduationStatus", 
         null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn- 
          primary btn-lg"> Process !</button>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            }
```

Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index(string graduationStatus)
        {
            ViewBag.GraduationStatus = new SelectList(db.Graduated_Students.Select(m => m.GraduationStatus).Distinct().ToList());

            var graduates = db.Graduated_Students.Where(student => student.GraduationStatus != null);

            return View(graduates.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: You have FormMethod.Post in your view and Your Index Method is Get or Post? If you have not specified any httpverb than it will be Get by default so change FormMethod.Get.

Comment: Done but it still not working...

Comment: change your code to    var graduates = db.Graduated_Students.Where(student => 
     student.GraduationStatus ==graduationStatus);

Comment: That works fine ! BUT when i get to the page there is nothing showing and I want to show all graduates and then be able to filter!  thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you don't need to filter on initail page load. graduationStatus will be null on initial load so add a condition to check if graduationStatus has some value. like this

```
   public ActionResult Index(string graduationStatus)
    {
      var graduates = db.Graduated_Students.Where(student => student.GraduationStatus != null);
        ViewBag.GraduationStatus = new SelectList(db.Graduated_Students.Select(m => m.GraduationStatus).Distinct().ToList());
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(graduationStatus))
         {
             graduates = graduates .Where(student => student.GraduationStatus == graduationStatus);
         }


        return View(graduates.ToList());
    }
```